# Is there a way to enable seeing the latest logs for Slapd when I use "service slapd status"

Tags: service, openldap, status, slapd, osixia

I have two different Linux operating systems that each have their own Slapd configuration, and one of them has a feature that I'd also like to have in the other, but I'm unsure how to get it.

When I execute the *service slapd status* command on my Ubuntu WSL virtual machine, it presents me with the latest log entries (see the picture below), which have been very useful for troubleshooting.
[image]

I want to have the same logging capabilities on a Linux (Docker) container, namely the [osixia/openldap container](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap), which is running *slapd* as well. When I execute *service slapd status* on there, I'm merely being told that the service is running, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to expand the information presented when I use *service slapd status*, so that I get the same results in the osixia/openldap container as in the Ubuntu WSL virtual machine?